# How can I use Fubu's DisplayConversionRegistry to convert values differently for Edit vs. DisplayFor?

Tags: fubumvc

I'm using my own DisplayConversionRegistry descendant to convert values for display in FubuMVC. This works great for date format consistency and the like. However, I find myself trying to format/convert some types of values differently when output in my views via Edit vs. DisplayFor.

For example, I want to display Money values with the currency symbol when output with DisplayFor. However, I do **not** want the currency symbol output when I use Edit. I also have other scenarios where I need differently formatted values for display than for editors.

Is there a way to do this with DisplayConversionRegistry, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to introduce a separated convention for Editors to override what you have configured in your DisplayConversionRegistry implementation.
You could do this in two ways:

1. Adding the expression right into your FubuRegistry class (useful for one-offs): 
   https://gist.github.com/3741460
2. Supply your own HtmlConventionRegistry class and register it into your FubuRegistry (useful if you already have a HtmlConventionRegistry implementor in your codebase):
   https://gist.github.com/3741471

Comment: This is what I've done thus far. My DisplayConversionRegistry introduces the formatted value and my HtmlConventionRegistry reverts editors of the same type to the RawValue. Thanks for the verification.